# How to import/restore MySQL InnoDB from Dump Project Folder

Tags: mysql

I tried to restore my database from dump folder but having errors about foreignkey constraints. I observed that the scripts are executed in alphabetical order, not sorted by table relationship.

Unlike self-contained file, the table are sorted by table relationships; thus restoring it has no issues.

Comment: Run this query first:`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` then restore database.once restore is completed execute this:`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

Comment: This fixed my problem. However I set it globally  **SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0** since I'm executing my script on a different instance.